# How to draw a proper surface with ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I've got this data, which if I plot with `ListPointPlot`, looks like this:

[image: Using ListPointPlot]

[image: Using ListPlot3D]

I just want to make a cone through those points, a simple cone like thing which is empty on the inside. I'm very very new to *Mathematica* so please be a little detailed in your answer...

Edit: the data can be imported from pastebin via

```
`Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/6VGiR4dc"]`
```

Somebody put my question on hold because it was incomplete in terms of the data but now the data has been provided.

Unfortunately, the excellent suggestion by ubpdqn to increase the `MaxPlotPoints` doesn't work for this data.

Comment: Perhaps something simple like `ListSurfacePlot3D[pts]` or `ConvexHullMesh[pts]` will give you what you need?

Comment: What you are asking isn't simple. Though we can clearly see that these points describe a 2D surface embedded in 3D, how do you find that programmatically.  `ListSurfacePlot3D` may be the answer, but I think you will have the best results if you make the data available for testing. If you go to pastebin.com you can paste the data there and put the link here.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your answers, but still getting no proper surface, tried maxpoints thing............Here's my data...I still can't get a proper surface.... pastebin.com/6VGiR4dc

Comment: You are right, using `MaxPlotPoints` just make it that much worse:  `pts = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/6VGiR4dc"];
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts, MaxPlotPoints -> #] & /@ {10, 20, 50, 60, 100, 
  200}`

Comment: so is there anything that can be done??

Comment: @JasonB when I posted my answer I did not see the link to the data. I do not have time to look at it at present. The behaviour with increasing `MaxPlotPoints` is disappointing. Obviously my contrived example just had smooth enough data.

Comment: @ubpdqn Of course, sometimes we make some example data.  This is a tricky issue that's come up before, how to make a surface just from a set of points.  Look at your example but turn the number of points up to 100 and it goes haywire.

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas Since your data us so regularly spaced, you might have luck using `Nearest` to make triangles out of the data.

Comment: Not working....My points are distributed around a hydrostatic line....can that help in any way.....i really need the surface through those points...

Comment: As a compromise, you can get a hull of the points via `ConvexHullMesh[pts]`. You can even `TriangulateMesh[...]` that and get a simplified hull.

Comment: convexHullmesh doesn't give me the surface in a proper coordinate system...it just gives me a cone...

Comment: `Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts],Axes->True,Boxed->True]`

Comment: Can you please also tell me to hide the lines on the final thing. I mean just the lines, and leave the rest of the cone...

Comment: `ConvexHullMesh[pts, PlotTheme -> "Polygons"]`

Answer (score 9):

Just to put some "flesh" in the absence of provision of data. [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html) can deal with relatively smooth data but may need [`MaxPlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) option to get a reasonable result as seen in this toy example:

```
fun[u_, v_] := {Cos[v] Sech[u], u - Tanh[u], Sech[u] Sin[v]}
tab = Catenate@Table[fun[u, v], {u, 0, 2, 0.1}, {v, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
p = ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, BoxRatios -> 1,
    Mesh -> None];
p3 = ListPointPlot3D[tab, BoxRatios -> 1];
sp = ListSurfacePlot3D[tab, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1];
spm = ListSurfacePlot3D[tab, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> 50];
Grid[{{"Plot3D", "ListPointPlot3D", "ListSurfacePlot3D", 
   "ListSurfacePlot3D with MaxPLotPoints->50"}, {p, p3, sp, spm}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your answers, but still getting no proper surface, tried maxpoints thing............Here's my data...I still can't get a proper surface....

http://pastebin.com/6VGiR4dc

Answer (score 2):

(from my comment/deleted answer :)

You could also use `ConvexHullMesh` Ala-

```
pts = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/6VGiR4dc"];
Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts, PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to remove the flat part, to get the cone shape, then it's fairly easy to do in this case.  Just remove any polygons whose normal vector is parallel to the largest polygon's normal vector.  http://pastebin.com/raw/RNaQ0SCF